# How the electric water heater and stove works?

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, electricity

I notice that some appliances have heating  elements such as electric stove and water heater. I know that both of them using heating elements maybe some type of a resistor or something. I want to know more about them since I notice in my house, the hot water coming out of the tap shocks me. So maybe the earth wire is not connected but in which case, this happen ? Is it because the the heating elements in the electric water heater got rusted thus water more conductive ?  Does anyone have any links that explain the working principle of each devices please? I need them. [image]

[image]

Comment: *hot water coming out of the tap shocks me* This means the electrical insulation of the heating element failed. The water heater needs a new heating element. Buying a new water heater of better quality is a better idea.

Comment: You need an electrician to come to your house and figure this out, right now. This is potentially very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

The outside of the element is a metal tube, which must be earthed for safety.  Inside that is a length of resistance wire, such as a nichrome alloy.  The gap between the resistance wire and the outer tube is filled with heatproof mineral insulation.

As the element gets old, the outer tube can develop holes, letting water in.  At this point, the element needs replacing.